# Whats the MS Ajax equivalent for jQuery ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a *resolute and unyielding need* to find the MS AJAX equivalent of jQuery.ajaxStop.
And I would like to write it in a fail safe way so that I dont get the `Sys is undefined` error
Could anybody help me out with this?

Comment: whats MS AJAX ? I thought they just included vanilla jquery

Comment: @NimChimpsky: the AJAX that comes with *that unholy* UpdatePanels in ASP.NET WebForms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`add_endRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) handler which is global to MS Ajax:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ajaxRequestComplete);

var ajaxRequestComplete = function (sender, args) {
    console.log('done');
    // your code goes here
}
```

**Edit**: You can combine it with [`isInAsyncPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383989.aspx) which indicates whether the `PageRequestManager` object is processing a postback:

```
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ajaxRequestComplete);

 var ajaxRequestComplete = function (sender, args) {
     if(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
         // your code goes here
     }
 }
```